# Get the next div wrt to current one with same class names

Tags: jquery

How can I find the next  with the same class as the current one. using jquery

I have a `<div>` with `class="help"`, now when some clicks on a button inside this  I want to select the next  with the same "help" class.

```
<div class="help">  
     <div>....OTHER HTML CONTENT......<div>
     <input type='submit' class='ok'>
</div>
<div>....OTHER HTML CONTENT......<div>
<div class="help"></div>
<div>....OTHER HTML CONTENT......<div>
<div>....OTHER HTML CONTENT......<div>
<div>....OTHER HTML CONTENT......<div>
<div class="help"></div>
<div>....OTHER HTML CONTENT......<div>
<div class="help"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the elements are **not** siblings, you could do something like this:

```
var $elements = $('.someClass');

$elements.click(function() {
    var $nextElement = $elements.eq($elements.index(this) + 1);
});
```

**Reference:** [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/S7W8P/)

Answer (score 2):

To find the next element which has the same class you can use `nextAll` with a selector to select the first one.

```
$('input').click(function(){
     var a = $(this).parent();  
    a.nextAll("."+a.attr('class')+":first");    
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/CwSTC/

Comment: +1 for `.nextAll()`, have u try with `.hasClass()` method with `.nextAll()`??

Comment: @diEcho `nextAll` accepts only a selector. Of course you could select all elements, and then filter them with `hasClass`, but presumably this is a slightly faster method, as it can stop getting the next elements as soon as it has met the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all your `help` divs are siblings, and that the button is always a child of one of those, what you need in your `.click()` handler is:

```
$(this).parent().nextAll('.help').first();
```

(kudos to @Niklas for making me check `.next()` and realising it wasn't right)

Comment: I think `.next()` only works if `help` is the immediate next sibling.

Comment: @Paul yes - was fixing that while you commented.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function to handle the button click, you can access the parent div and then from there access the next help div.  See below.

```
function btn_click_handler()
{
  var btn = $(this);
  var next_help_div = btn.parent("div.help").nextAll("div.help:first");
  <your code here>
}
```

Comment: That would return the **first** element under the parent, not the next one from the one clicked.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  nextAll (as you've used in your answer) is better.  I'll edit my answer to reflect that.